# Integrate Android app + Amazon EC2 + Amazon RDS

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm sorry if this question seems repetitive, but I've searched quite a lot and I couldn't find exactly what I need.

When I started developing my android app, I created a webservice (java restful) and my database all locally, everything works perfect. But now I decided to send everything to the cloud. I created an instance in Amazon RDS, populated my mysql, and everything works fine as well, but still using my webservice locally.

My question is if I'm going in a good track. I want to put my webservice in my instance on Amazon EC2. Is it possible? And How can I access my webservice from my app?

Thanks in advance,

Rodrigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. All you need to do is install your java app on one or more ec2 instances. You should assign a DNS record to the instance and use that within your app to connect to the instance.

Comment: Thank you very much datasage. I'll do this immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which might save you some time/effort would be setting up an Elastic Beanstalk environment. It consists on a full Application + Database layer, and will automatically have a FQDN assigned to it. It means you will have something like "yourfancydomain.elasticbeanstalk.com" or similar, a Tomcat instance responding to requests to that domain, and a MySQL RDS database under it.